# Using avconv how do you make a linear16 file for Google Speech to Text

Tags: avconv, google-speech-api

I'm trying to use avconv to make a LINEAR16 raw file for Google's speech to text, but whenever I try, I get a really slow file when I try to play it back using the play command in the documentation:

```
play --rate=16000 --bits=16 --endian=little --encoding=signed-integer --channels=1 out.raw
```

What's the right way to make this kind of a conversion?

Answer (score 1):

It took some experimentation, but I was able to get it working by explicitly stating the sample rate, number of channels, and output format:

```
avconv -i michael_queen_v._ed_schultz_cl.mp3 -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 16k out.raw
```

`-f`: This forces the output encoding, since `.raw` isn't apparently enough for it to know what to do.

`-ac 1`: Mono

`-ar 16k`: This sounds like [a gun](http://guns.wikia.com/wiki/Armalite_AR-16), which is depressing, but this sets the sample rate to 16000MHz.